# Change check box background color

Tags: css, input, checkbox, background-color

Good afternoon.

I'm having a problem changing the background color of the checkboxes that are selected.

[CheckBox to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOVMz.png)

I've seen options on the internet and some questions right here in the stack. But none of them were successful. Below is the DOM image where the elements are inserted.

[Dom about element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiZ1b.png)

The last code I tested was this and it still didn't work

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked:after{
    background-color: red !important;
    color: blue !important;
}
```

Aimed to have a background in this color # FFEA00 when checked and the arrow to be # 000 when checked.

Best regards and thanks for the help

Comment: `:after` doesn't work with `input`. Apply the style to the `label`

Comment: I'd like to make sure I get your request: you want the checkbox to have a #FFEA00 background and the checkmark (that is usually white), to be black?

Comment: Hello @LaurentC and many thanks for the reply. 
Yes I wanted the background color when it was checked in yellow (#FFEA00) and the arrow in black.
I noticed that the blue (the color I want to change) is the default color of the Chrome browser. In the case of firefox it no longer has a background color and has a border. In other words, they are browser default behaviors, I think.
I've tried to customize the label and other options without success

Comment: @LaurentC some help please :)

Comment: @PedroEstevesAntunes ok let me have a look at this, I'm not sure these elements are customizable, but I'l doublecheck for you. And, *yes*, defaults vary from one browser to another, absolutely.

Comment: Update: Found a solution, I'll post the answer in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yellow background when checked, black arrow when checked. It's here:

```css
.checkbox-label {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    clear: both;
}

.checkbox-label input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox-label .checkbox-custom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}


.checkbox-label input:checked ~ .checkbox-custom {
    background-color: #FFEA00;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
    opacity:1;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

.checkbox-label .checkbox-custom::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: 12px;
    top: 12px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid #000;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0);
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0);
    opacity:1;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}


.checkbox-label input:checked ~ .checkbox-custom::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  opacity:1;
  left: 8px;
  top: 3px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 12px;
  border: solid #000000;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox-container">
        <label class="checkbox-label">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
        </label>
</div>
```

Comment: A word of caution with styling default elements like this: it might (will) behave differently in different browsers of even browsers versions, so it is usually not really recommended. This was tested and fully works in 85.0.4183.83 (Chrome).

Comment: codepen : https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/WNwMZoR

Comment: Great LaurentC. Thank you very much. I have the problem of not being able to edit the classes or add, since the HTML is built by a wordpress pluggin. I think I will have to use JavaScript to add classes to the elements.
I will test and then give feedback. Thank you very much

Comment: My pleasure, but if you want a little bit more help with implementing your CSS in your WP website let me know I have a lot of experience with WP and some free time today. I feel that you don't need to use JS to add classes to your HTML elements... You can find my email contact here: laurentchevrette (dot) digital    ....cheers - and thanks for accepting my answer.